# Question about nullity and rank

Tags: linear-transformations

If there is a T : V ->W

and I found out that null space is 0 and nullity 0

If nullity is 0, doesn't that mean that dimT(V) is equal to dimV ?

and when I describe range of T(V), Can I just say that range of T(V) is vector space itself?

Answer (score 1):

No, if $\dim\text{Nul}T=0$ then $\dim T(V)=\dim V$.

Unless you know more about $W$, that's all you can say.

Comment: Shouldn't $Τ$ be linear in order to apply rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: Yes. If T isnt linear we cant claim to know anything about its image or kernel or whether theyre even subspaces

Comment: Fair enough! I missed reading the tag, which "implies" that $T$ is linear!